# calculate fast row means

Tags: r, optimization, datatable

I am trying to calculate row means in a big datatable, e.g.

```
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(a = rnorm(4000000), b = rnorm(4000000), c = rnorm(4000000), 
                 d = rnorm(4000000), e = rnorm(4000000))
```

It also contains random NAs and many rows with full NAs (I don't know how to randomly insert these in the above example).

I am using the following code to calc the row sums:

```
DT[,sums:= rowMeans(.SD,na.rm=T)]
```

But it takes several minutes.
Is there any way to optimize this code/a solution that is faster than rowMeans?

Comment: `rowMeans` to calculate row sums? Why so?

Comment: All you need to do is `DT[,sums:= rowSums(.SD,na.rm=TRUE)]`

Comment: Remember that `data.table` is still a `data.frame` therefore you can still apply to it the same method you used with `data.frame` objects

Comment: As @Seymour said, the fact that you still use data.frame might make it slower. Try converting your data.frame to matrix. I've seen in some debates that it makes calculations quicker.

Comment: @DJV what you are saying is definitely true! Convert it to matrix makes it exponentially faster!

Comment: Hello everyone, thanks for the comments. But as it is a big data table which also contains columns of other classes than numeric, I cannot convert to matrix. Only if I delete those I guess. Also sorry for the confusion on my side, I meant rowMeans not rowSums.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding  @Seymour comments and mine.

Comparing data.table and matrix:

```
require(rbenchmark)
require(data.table)

#Sample data
  set.seed(1)
  DT_df <- data.table(a = rnorm(4000000), b = rnorm(4000000), c = rnorm(4000000), 
                   d = rnorm(4000000), e = rnorm(4000000))
  set.seed(1)
  DT_Matrix <- matrix(rexp(2e+07, rate=.1), ncol=5)

#Benchmark
    benchmark("data.table" = {
    DT_df[,sums:= rowMeans(.SD,na.rm=T)]
  },
  "Matrix" = {
    cbind(DT_Matrix, rowMeans(DT_Matrix, na.rm=T))
    },
  replications = 1000,
  columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed",
              "relative", "user.self", "sys.self"))
```

Results:

```
        test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
1 data.table         1000  264.30    1.146    254.08     7.78
2     Matrix         1000  230.64    1.000    213.72    16.29
```

Comment: thanks that is helpful, but for me kind of a workaround, because later on I would have to convert to datatable again, and before converting to matrix, I would have to delete some columns. If it's the only way, I will do it though (I cannot upvote you yet as I have less than 15 reput)

Comment: Glad I could help :). I don't know either if I would have done this workaround. My thoughts would be how many times do I need to convert back-and-forth (this takes time too), how big the files/variables are and maybe wrapping under a function would make it faster (usually does). In addition, data.tables are known to be quick anyway - try reading tutorials/syntax. Maybe you could find something quicker(?)